# Knockout.js Adding a Property to Child Elements

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

My code doesn't create a new property under the child element of knockout viewmodel that is mapped by knockout.mapping.fromJS.

I have:

```
//model from Entity Framework
console.log(ko.mapping.toJSON(model));
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model, mappingOption);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
console.log(ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel));
```

The first console.log outputs:

```
{
  "Id": 0,
  "CurrentUser": {
    "BoardIds": [
      {
        "Id": 0
      }
    ],
    "Id": 1,
    "UserName": "foo",
    "IsOnline": true
  },
  "Boards": []
}
```

And then the mappingOption is:

```
var mappingOption = {
    create: function (options) {
        var modelBase = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);

        modelBase.CurrentUser.UserName = ko.observable(model.CurrentUser.UserName).extend({ rateLimit: 1000 });

        //some function definitions

        return modelBase;
    },
    'CurrentUser': {
        create: function (options) {
            options.data.MessageToPost = ko.observable("test");
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
        }
    }
};
```

I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526417/knockout-mapping-customize-create-with-nested-objects) to create the custom mapping, but it seemed not working as the second console.log outputs the same JSON to the first one.

Also, I tried to create nested mapping option based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673928/adding-properties-to-the-view-model-created-by-using-the-knockout-js-mapping-plu) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862115/how-do-i-customize-knockout-mapping-creation-in-nested-model) but it didn't work too.

```
var mappingOption = {
    create: function (options) {

        //modelBase, modifing UserName and add the functions

        var mappingOption2 = {
            'CurrentUser': {
                create: function (options) {
                    return (new(function () {
                        this.MessageToPost = ko.observable("test");
                        ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, mappingOption2, this);
                    })());
                }
            }
        }
        return ko.mapping.fromJS(modelBase, mappingOption2);
    }
};
```

How can I correctly add a new property to the original viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the mapping [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) for ko.toJS (toJS and toJSON work the same way as stated in the document)

> - **Unmapping**
>
> If you want to convert your mapped object back to a regular JS object, use:
> `var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel);`
> This will create an unmapped object **containing only the properties of the mapped object that were part of your original JS object**

If you want the json to include properties you've added manually either use `ko.toJSON` instead of `ko.mapping.toJSON` to include everything, or use the include option when first creating your object to specify which properties to add.

```
var mapping = {
    'include': ["propertyToInclude", "alsoIncludeThis"]
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

**EDIT:** In your specific case your mapping options are conflicting with each other. You've set special instructions for the CurrentUser field but then overridden them in the create function. Here's what I think your mapping options should look like:

```
var mappingOption = { 
  'CurrentUser': {
    create: function (options) {
      var currentUser = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {
        'UserName': {
          create: function(options){
            return ko.observable(options.data);
          }
        },
        'include': ["MessageToPost"]
      });
      currentUser.MessageToPost = ko.observable("test");
      return ko.observable(currentUser).extend({ rateLimit: 1000 });
    }
  }
};
```

and here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/qnfeeg5t/) for a working example

Comment: Thanks for answering, I managed to output the entire viewmodel by removing "mapping" from toJS. However, indeed my interest was the way to add a new property to a child array of the viewmodel. My code successfully add a property to the root level of the viewmodel, but it fails to do so when it comes to a nested level.

Comment: @seed.of.apricot Did this resolve your issue or are you still having trouble getting it to work?

Comment: Thanks for your edit, the code worked well and I will modify it to integrate with my project.